# my images are not displaying when I run it in react

Tags: reactjs

> The code below is my data.jsx file where I used to store images, the title of the images, and description of the images. I have a problem importing images from another folder named Images. The Images folder and data.jsx file are both inside my component file
>
> The vs code compiled it successfully but when I run it I just cannot see the result.

```
import img1 from './Images/jisoo.png'
import img2 from './Images/blackpink.png'
import img3 from './Images/jennie.jpg'


export const sliderItems = [
 {
    id:1,
    img:{img1},
    title:"CNY SALES",
    desc:"DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR THE BEST SELLING PRODUCTS.",
    bg:"f5fafd",
},
{
    id:2,
    img:{img2},
    title:"ANY SALES",
    desc:"DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR THE BEST SELLING PRODUCTS.",
    bg:"fcf1ed",
},
{
    id:3,
    img:{img3},
    title:"BNY SALES",
    desc:"DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR THE BEST SELLING PRODUCTS.",
    bg:"fbf0f4",
}]
```

[Click on this link and you can the picture of my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYDH4.png)

Comment: Kindly add the HTML part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use { img } outside jsx(html) this will create an js object.

You are doing something like this which is not correct.

```
{
    id:3,
    img:{img3 : img3},
    title:"BNY SALES",
    desc:"DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR THE BEST SELLING PRODUCTS.",
    bg:"fbf0f4",
}
```

Use like this

```
{
    id:3,
    img:img3,
    title:"BNY SALES",
    desc:"DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR THE BEST SELLING PRODUCTS.",
    bg:"fbf0f4",
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much my brothaaaa!Love u sooo much.I was not aware of that

Comment: Hi @CopperCleric Kindly mark the answer correct if it is working perfectly. Thanks